# MacOS Where can I find what was in /usr/etc?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, homebrew, lua

I recently was trying to reinstall all of the Homebrew libraries and accidentally deleted `/usr/etc` instead of `/usr/local/etc` using `rm -rf`. When trying to reinstall torch-rnn, I got this error:

```
Prefix set to /Users/why262/Documents/Programming/torch/install
Installing Lua version: LUAJIT21
/Users/why262/Documents/Programming/torch/exe/luajit-rocks/luajit-2.1/src/host/minilua.c:34:10: fatal error: 
      'math.h' file not found
#include <math.h>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [exe/luajit-rocks/luajit-2.1/CMakeFiles/minilua.dir/src/host/minilua.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [exe/luajit-rocks/luajit-2.1/CMakeFiles/minilua.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
install_name_tool: error: unable to read SDK settings for '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk'
install_name_tool: error: unable to read SDK settings for '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk'
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: can't open file: /Users/why262/Documents/Programming/torch/install/lib/libluajit.dylib (No such file or directory)
./install.sh: line 107: /Users/why262/Documents/Programming/torch/install/bin/luarocks: No such file or directory
Installing common Lua packages
```

I think it is because I deleted `/usr/etc`. Is there any way to get the files back?

Comment: I have `math.h` in xcode.app.  You could ensure it is installed and xcode-select has path set.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980759/xcode-select-active-developer-directory-error/17980786#17980786

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to restore that directory from your own backup; `/usr/etc` was specific to your system.

macOS (at least 10.14.x Mojave) doesn't have a `/usr/etc`. It has a `/etc` which is a symlink to `/private/etc`, but no `/usr/etc`. So your `/usr/etc` must be something you installed.